# CAPL how to define envVar in the FDX description file XML

Tags: xml, capl, canoe

I'm trying to control Canoe config using FDX protocole, I can until now control start/stop measurement, frames, signals and sysvar request , but the problem is that i want to change envVar values , which not defined in the VECTOR FDX description file exemple (.xml).
I know that for a signal :

```
 < identifier>SigEngineSpeed< /identifier>

 < signal value="raw" name="EngineSpeed"/ >
```

and for a sysvar :

```
   <identifier>VarHazardLightsSwitch</identifier>

   <sysvar name="HazardLightsSwitch" namespace="FDX"/>
```

So could you help me please with the structure to define an envVar in the FDX description file.

Answer (score 0):

without any answer from anyone, i have found the solution myself.
So to define an environment variable in an XML file ( for exemple to enable/disable a checkbox in canoe panel from client soft (labwindows/cvi for my case ) :

an exemple :

"<"item size="1" offset="0" type="int8">

```
        "<"envvar name="envvar name">
            <name>envvarname</name>
        </envvar>
```

"<"/item>

this solution workd but can be improved!

Comment: It would help reading,  if you use formatting

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's easier if you use the VECTOR FDX editor, it's very simple.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCLFV.png)

Comment: Yes , Thank you, it's the best solution.